# Getting the words from a sentence and storing them in a vector of strings

Tags: c++

Alright, guys ...

Here's my set that has all the letters. I'm defining a word as consisting of consecutive letters from the set.

```
const char LETTERS_ARR[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
const std::set<char> LETTERS_SET(LETTERS_ARR, LETTERS_ARR + sizeof(LETTERS_ARR)/sizeof(char));
```

I was hoping that this function would take in a string representing a sentence and return a vector of strings that are the individual words in the sentence.

```
std::vector<std::string> get_sntnc_wrds(std::string S) { 
    std::vector<std::string> retvec;
    std::string::iterator it = S.begin(); 
    while (it != S.end()) { 
        if (LETTERS_SET.count(*it) == 1) { 
            std::string str(1,*it);
            int k(0);
            while (((it+k+1) != S.end()) && (LETTERS_SET.count(*(it+k+1) == 1))) { 
                str.push_back(*(it + (++k)));
            }
            retvec.push_back(str);
            it += k;
        }
        else { 
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return retvec;
}
```

For instance, the following call should return a vector of the strings "Yo", "dawg", etc.

```
std::string mystring("Yo, dawg, I heard you life functions, so we put a function inside your function so you can derive while you derive.");
std::vector<std::string> mystringvec = get_sntnc_wrds(mystring);
```

But everything isn't going as planned. I tried running my code and it was putting the entire sentence into the first and only element of the vector. My function is very messy code and perhaps you can help me come up with a simpler version. I don't expect you to be able to trace my thought process in my pitiful attempt at writing that function.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a bracketing issue, my advice is (almost) never put in more brackets than are necessary, it's only confuses things

```
       while (it+k+1 != S.end() && LETTERS_SET.count(*(it+k+1)) == 1) {
```

Your code compares the character with `1` not the return value of `count`.

Also although count does return an integer in this context I would simplify further and treat the return as a boolean

```
       while (it+k+1 != S.end() && LETTERS_SET.count(*(it+k+1))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// true if the argument is whitespace, false otherwise
bool space(char c)
{
  return isspace(c);
}

// false if the argument is whitespace, true otherwise
bool not_space(char c)
{
  return !isspace(c);
}

vector<string> split(const string& str)
{
  typedef string::const_iterator iter;
  vector<string> ret;
  iter i = str.begin();

  while (i != str.end()) 
  {
    // ignore leading blanks
    i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);
    // find end of next word
    iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);
    // copy the characters in [i, j)
    if (i != str.end())
      ret.push_back(string(i, j));
    i = j;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The `split` function will return a `vector` of `string`s, each element containing one word.

This code is taken from the [Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) book, so it's not mine, but it works. There are other superb examples of using containers and algorithms for solving every-day problems in this book. I could even get a one-liner to show the contents of a file at the output console. Highly recommended.

Comment: There may be characters other than the whitespaces to be used for splitting (like commas).

Comment: Is not that hard to modify the predicate (space and not_space) in the find_if algorithm to take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [string steam](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string sentence = "And I feel fine...";
    std::istringstream iss(sentence);
    std::vector<std::string> split;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(split));

    // This is to print the vector
    for(auto iter = split.begin();
        iter != split.end();
        ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even I thought of similar approach, but there may be characters other than the whitespaces to be used for splitting (like commas).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal That is an easy fix as you could replace all "," with " , " in the string before you parse it.

Comment: Well there can be other non-alpha characters like '.' '(' '*' etc. If you need to replace those characters, then IMO the advantage of using stringstream is lost.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Not sure the `STD` library has something that will deal with all of these cases, I believe this is the closet you will get without writing your own custom way. Besides, the OP is currently using `isspace` which doesn't deal with those cases.

Comment: OP is not using isspace(). It is used in one of the other answers posted. OP has defined a set of valid characters and the string is split if the character does not match with any of the characters in the set.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Ops, sorry about that, I guess I got confused. But my point is still valid, this is as close as you will get if you want to use the `std` library and the only way I know that doesn't require writing your own custom way is to just put a space between the characters that you want to also split. It is a minor inconvenience but will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I would use another more simple approach based on member functions of class std::string. For example

```
    const char LETTERS[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    std::string s( "This12 34is 56a78 test." );

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    for ( std::string::size_type first = s.find_first_of( LETTERS, 0 ); 
          first != std::string::npos; 
          first = s.find_first_of( LETTERS, first ) )
    {
        std::string::size_type last = s.find_first_not_of( LETTERS, first );
        v.push_back(
            std::string( s, first, last == std::string::npos ? std::string::npos : last - first ) );
        first = last;
    }

    for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you make 2 mistakes, I have correct in the following code.

First, it should be

> while (((it+k+1) != S.end()) && (LETTERS_SET.count(*(it+k+1)) == 1))

and, it should move to next by

> it += (k+1);

and the code is

```
    std::vector<std::string> get_sntnc_wrds(std::string S) { 
    std::vector<std::string> retvec;
    std::string::iterator it = S.begin(); 
    while (it != S.end()) { 
        if (LETTERS_SET.count(*it) == 1) { 
            std::string str(1,*it);
            int k(0);

            while (((it+k+1) != S.end()) && (LETTERS_SET.count(*(it+k+1)) == 1)) { 
                str.push_back(*(it + (++k)));
            }
            retvec.push_back(str);
            it += (k+1);
        }
        else { 
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return retvec;
}
```

The output have been tested.